# Golang update json field with arbitrary json

Tags: json, go

Given some json string, and a jsonpath

```
myJson := `{
  "test": {
    "foo1": "bar1",
    "foo2": "bar2"
  }
}`

jsonPath := "test.foo2"
```

and another string containing arbitrary json

```
arbitraryJson := `{
  "a": "apple",
  "b": [1,2]
}`
```

How can I update the original json string, to contain the arbitrary json at the specified path?

```
// expected output:
`{
  "test": {
    "foo1": "bar1",
    "foo2": {
      "a": "apple",
      "b": [1,2]
    }
  }
}`
```

Answer (score 1):

Found the solution

Using https://github.com/tidwall/sjson

I was originally setting the json string directly, which just caused it to be interpreted as a string

```
// This doesn't work:
newJson, err := sjson.Set(MyJson, jsonPath, arbitraryJson)
// output
`{
  "test": {
    "foo1": "bar1",
    "foo2": "{\"a\": \"apple\",\"b\": [1,2]}"
  }
}`
```

But just unmarshalling the arbitrary json first gives the intended result

```
var unmarshalled any
_ = json.Unmarshal([]byte(arbitraryJson), &unmarshalled)
newJson, err := sjson.Set(MyJson, jsonPath, unmarshalled)
// output
`{
  "test": {
    "foo1": "bar1",
    "foo2": {
      "a": "apple",
      "b": [1,2]
    }
  }
}`
```